# bash: Search/replace for strings matching ${FOO}-style patterns literally

Tags: bash, unix, replace, grep, arguments

I´m building a bash script and i want to replace "${PRODUCT_NAME}" with a "WORD" for example.
The problem is "$", in bash $ stands for an argument so when i run the script

```
echo "Replace ${PRODUCT_NAME} with $1 in document.txt"

for file in $(grep -il ${PRODUCT_NAME} ~/Documents/tmp/document.txt)   
do   
   sed -e "s/${PRODUCT_NAME}/$3/g" $file > /tmp/tempfile.tmp   
   mv /tmp/tempfile.tmp $file   
done
```

the script recognizes the ${PRODUCT_NAME} as an argument and not as a word that i want to replace. How do i make it recognize that "${PRODUCT_NAME}" is a word and not an argument, so i can replace it?

Comment: You might want to mention that you wanted to replace a *literal* occurrence of `${PRODUCT_NAME}` rather than the value of that *Bash variable*...

Comment: That is why i used the quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that your `sed` script actually needs to use `\${PRODUCT_NAME}` rather than `${PRODUCT_NAME}` as the search-pattern, because in a POSIX Basic Regular Expression, `$` means "end of line" rather than "dollar sign". That out of the way . . .

In Bash, you can either quote a dollar-sign with a backslash:

```
echo "Replace \${PRODUCT_NAME} with $1 in document.txt"

for file in $(grep -il ${PRODUCT_NAME} ~/Documents/tmp/document.txt)
do
   sed -e "s/\\\${PRODUCT_NAME}/$3/g" $file > /tmp/tempfile.tmp
   mv /tmp/tempfile.tmp $file
done
```

or else use single-quotes (which are like double-quotes except that they don't allow `$`-based expansion, and don't handle `\`):

```
echo 'Replace ${PRODUCT_NAME} with '"$1 in document.txt"

for file in $(grep -il ${PRODUCT_NAME} ~/Documents/tmp/document.txt)
do
   sed -e 's/\${PRODUCT_NAME}/'"$3/g" $file > /tmp/tempfile.tmp
   mv /tmp/tempfile.tmp $file
done
```

(By the way, is it intentional that your `echo` line uses `$1` while your `sed` line uses `$3`? It seems like they should both use the same parameter.)

Comment: Thanks man! It works, you forgot the backslash in the grep comand